# Paging leaderboard query in a dynamic environment with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple leaderboard system. How can I centre a page of results on a users score when this requires 2 queries (one to get the position of their score in the table, another to get the page surrounding it) and it's possible that a new score might arrive between them. Is locking the table the only way? Or is there some sort of atomic method? If I embed a query in the offset values, is that atomic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the easiest solutions is to get the visible page + a few extra on either side.  You should nearly always have enough data to center the UI on the active player even if new records have come in.

However, you should always be prepared to deal with not having enough data to center the player - top and bottom of the leaderboard, etc.

If the player doesn't show up at all in the page, you have to make another request or two.  However, the odds of a player getting pushed out of a page in a short period of time (a few seconds to complete both queries) are very low, so as long as the UI doesn't hang, the experience should be fine.

Comment: Simple and elegant as always Matt :)